# Persist Nested Entity Spring Rest Data

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have a User Class

```
@Entity(name = "users")
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements UserDetails {

static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "username", nullable = false, unique = true)
private String username;

@Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
private String password;
}
```

Tied to a simple Repository

```
public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

And I have an Instructor Class that has a nested User object

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "instructors")
public class Instructor {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "instructor_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private Long id;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "course_id")
private List<Course> courses;
```

}

It is saved with the following repository

```
public interface InstructorRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Instructor, Long> {
```

}

The JSON I am posting

```
{
"user": {
    "id": 1
}
}
```

When I try to do a `POST` to `/instructors` . User is coming in null.  Is there something I am missing to get JPA to tie the two together?  I have tried adding `CascadeType.ALL` onto the field and that only throws a detached persist exception.

Comment: So your relation is many instructors to one user? Whic one do you persist user or instructor Have any code for that?

Comment: Sorry, I was trying many different things to see what would work. It is supposed to be one to one.  I have made the change and posted the repo code.

Comment: Post the JSON you are posting.

Comment: @AlanHay I have attached the JSON

Answer (score 0):

Leave the `CascadeType.ALL` to `Instructor` like you already tried:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user;
```

In addition add the following to `User`. Seems to work with me. It provides the mapping information and makes JPA treat `User` managed

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="user")//, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Instructor> instructors = new ArrayList<>();
```

I have commented out the `cascadeType` in the above  but it might be useful if you want to persist `User` wit all of its `Instructors`.

Comment: I was not at all clear about this in the question, and maybe I am just architecting this wrong...   So each user will have have one or more roles role (admin, teacher, student).  I have a course object, and each course is taught by one instructor and can have many students. I created instructor almost as if it were extending User.  So One to One may not be the best relationship as a User does not need be a user, but every Instructor will be a User.